# How to embed HTTP in lua 5.0.1?

Tags: http, server, lua, client, communication

I want to create a client/server communication but unfortunately I have to use lua 5.0.1. How can I make this work and compile it in a single file? 
Thx

Comment: It is absolutely unclear what you are asking.  Do you want to implement your own HTTP client/server in Lua?  Lua does not support sockets.  Also, how is Lua 5.0.1 a limitation?  What have you tried?

Comment: @HenriMenke Not necessarily my own, I just want to be able to communicate with a server from lua 5.0.1. I say 5.0.1 because I found this: https://github.com/daurnimator/lua-http 
but it's compatible only from 5.1 upwards.

Comment: So your question is actually “How can I use lua-http in Lua 5.0.1 or are there any alternatives?”

Comment: @HenriMenke Yes, and also how can I embed the http functionality into one single compiled file.

Comment: Lua is an interpreted language.  And as I said before, sockets are not supported so you need external library support.

Comment: I see, but what about http library in 5.0.1? Is there any other option?

Comment: I'm not aware of any, I guess Google is your friend here.  You might want to consider updating your system or ask the admin to update your system.  Lua 5.0.1 is 15 years old.

Comment: Unfortunately update is not an option since in my case the lua 5.0.1 is used by a video game to run the addon's scripts. Thank you for your answers